# Tapestry: startup order using @Startup and @Order annotations

Tags: java, tapestry

Consider some `AppModule` in `Tapestry` project.

I want to order sequence of actions, which must invoke on system startup.

Consider, I have two simple actions:

1)   Action, which must go first:

```
@Startup
public static void initMyApplication(Logger logger, LiquibaseService liquibaseService) {
    logger.info("Updating database by liquibase service...");
    liquibaseService.update();
    logger.info("update-db done.");
}
```

2) and the second one:

```
@Startup
@Order("after:LiquibaseService")
public static void doSomeChecks(HibernateSessionManager hsm) {
   ... 
}
```

I can not understand (even after reading documentation): **how can I specify order of such actions using `@Order` annotation?**

More specifically: what do I need to point into `@Order("after:<HERE>)`?

It seems, that constructions like:

`@Order("after:LiquibaseService")`

or

`@Order("after:initMyApplication")`

don't work. Actually my `startup` actions are invoked in arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `@Order` can be used with `@Startup` but what you can do is use `contributeRegistryStartup`. As it expects an `OrderedConfiguration` you can order your contributions.

```
public class MyModule1
{
  public static void contributeRegistryStartup(OrderedConfiguration<Runnable> configuration)
  {
    configuration.add("MyFirstContribution", new Runnable() { ... });
  }
}

public class MyModule2
{
  public static void contributeRegistryStartup(OrderedConfiguration<Runnable> configuration)
  {
    configuration.add("MySecondContribution", new Runnable() { ... }, "after:MyFirstContribution");
  }
}
```

Comment: yes I know about `contributeRegistryStartup` method. But I don't understand, how can I inject into those anonymous `Runnable` objects instances of desired services, like I did with my method `initMyApplication` (I mean instance of service `LiquibaseService`, while it is just an example). If you can provide me such example, it will be +1 and checked :)

Comment: yes, it actually works, I checked it. Thanks, it is an interesting decision.